# preg-replace(); parameter mismatch,pattern is a string while replacement is an array

Tags: laravel

Trying to resend login details to a user through his mail.what I want to do is after the user has click on the forgotten password link, a form is displayed requesting for his email to be posted.after the email has been posted, I check if the email corresponds to an email in the users table and send details.

Here my controller

```
Public function postResendPassword
{

    $posted = Input::get();

    $email = $posted['email'];

     $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();

    $user_password = 
    $user->password_confirmation;

    $user_username = $user->username;

    $user_email = $user->email;


    $to =  $user->email;

     $subject = " login details request";

     $message = 

      <h3>login details</h3>
      email : $user_email
        login password : $user_password

    regards;

    mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

how do I go about this and fix this error

Answer (score 0):

You aint fetching the result, so you're still in the query builder.

Change

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', $email);
```

To

```
$user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
```

Comment: I changed to $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first(); and I get this error exception

Comment: Preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string  while replacement is an array